# EC2 Spot instance Maximum runtime

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I read myself pretty much through all the online docs of EC2.
Still one question is unanswered to me:

**What is the maximum runtime of a spot instance (uninterrupted) ?**

everything is well documented for < 6h runtime. But what happens afterwards ? is the instance automatically terminated or does is keep running until the ressources are no more available ? somehow i didn`t find anything clear on this.

Thanks !

Comment: This is not related to programming.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the AWS documentation under [How Spot Instances Work](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/how-spot-instances-work.html):

> Spot Instances run until you terminate them or until Amazon EC2 must interrupt them (known as a Spot Instance interruption).

Therfore in theory an EC2 spot instance will run indefinitely until you terminate it or AWS [interrupts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-interruptions.html) it because your spot bid price is too low, or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Spot instances will not terminate until you do or it is interrupted from AWS side (Eg. The Spot price is greater than your maximum price). So your application should be able to handle these terminations gracefully. 
More details : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-interruptions.html

Also if you terminate it you will be charge for that hour. If AWS terminates it you are not charged for that hour.